# Quaternion algebra in characteristic $p$

Tags: fields, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Given a prime number $p$, can you give me concrete examples of fields $\mathbf F$ of characteristic $p$ and quaternion algebras $\mathbb H(\mathbf F)$ over $\mathbf F$ such that $\mathbb H(\mathbf F)$ is a (non-commutative) division ring ?

Comment: Take $\mathbf{F}=\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$ and $\mathbb{H}(F)$ the algebra with basis $1,i,j,k$ and relations $ij=-ji=k$, $i^2=X$, $j^2=Y$.

Comment: @abx, not when $p=2$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ is a finite field, the unique central division $F$-algebra is $F$ itself. This is Wedderburn's theorem :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem

In particular there is no central quaternion $F$-algebra. In contrast  there are central division $F$-algebras of arbitrary (square) dimension when e.g. $F$ is  a global field (a number field, or a function field over a finite field $F_{q}$) or a local field (a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}_p$, or a field of the form $F_q ((X))$, the field of Laurent series over a finite field $F_q$). All of this is classical and may be found in any lecture notes on the theory of Brauer group :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group

A. Weil, Basic Number Theory